# MaxQueryLookupFields property in SPWebApplication Class

Tags: powershell, web-application

Can anyone tell what the **MaxQueryLookupFields** property in **SPWebApplication** class is for?

**Edit 1**

> Gets or sets the maximum number of lookup fields that may be included
>   in a list item query.

This is the description which I found on the MSDN site, but I still don't have a clear idea about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MaxQueryLookupFields` is a limit that applies when you have a list or a query with a lots of lookup columns to prevent perfomance / load issues.

I think the default value is 8 (lookup columns).

Let's say you have a list with 10 lookup columns and you try to open a view displaying all these 10 columns. This view won't render, because the underlying query will hit the `MaxQueryLookupFields` limit. You'll receive an error message within the view's webpart.

Comment: Thank you, now i'm getting it. Actually I'm getting an error like "Value does not fall within the range" when I query data from lists or sites using Client Object Model. Is this because of this limited lookup fields? Any idea about this? I referred this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/15601/value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range-with-exception.aspx)

Comment: "Value does not fall within the range" is a very generic error message regarding indices, collections, etc. As you were asking about `MaxQueryLookupFields` you maybe should check first, if your query result doesn't contain more than 8 lookup columns. If this is not the case, you can ask a new / separate question here on StackExchange.SharePoint including the relevant pieces of your CSOM code, query, etc.